# Why gazebo pr2's attribute are circular and fix which can't be changed?

Tags: ros, pr2-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This picture:

[image: image description]

When I revise its attributed, all other same field would be changed at the same time.

What happened? How to change attribute?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30991/why-gazebo-pr2%27s-attribute-are-circular-and-fix-which-can%27t-be-changed?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-04-02**:
Hi Sam, please describe the question in more detail, which attributes and which fields are you referring to?  What changes were made where and what were you expecting to see, etc...  thanks.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-02**:
On red square, it shows the totally same attributes, such as name,static,mass... . When I change any one,the other red square will not change at the same time. I'm wondering why pr2 shows the same attribute,but other object will not show repeated attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gazebo GUI under Electric was written in wxwidgets and was probably quite buggy at best.  We thought of fixing it up but decided to move to QT based GUI in Fuerte.  The new QT based GUI will be more functional and user friendly.

If you need to change object attributes dynamically, I recommend writing a plugin and accessing the object class directly.  If you must do so in the GUI under Electric, please setup a very simple test case and file bug reports / submit patch.  Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0